# How check if Request.QueryString is not empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have my own `HandleErrorAttribute`, which reads data from `Exception` and `HttpContext`, insert them into template and send an e-mail to administrator. It usually works fine, but it some cases it breaks, when trying to check if `QueryString` is not empty.

```
var requestParams = "";
if (context.Request.QueryString != null && context.Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (String key in context.Request.QueryString.Keys)
    {
        requestParams += key + ": " + context.Request.QueryString[key] + "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    requestParams = "[ no query string data ]";
}
```

It breaks when checking condition (`NullReferenceException`), even if I can see in debug, that `QueryString` is not null and the `Keys.Count` is equal to 0.

What am I missing here? How to do a proper check for an empty `QueryString`?

Stacktrace:

```
w System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetQueryStringPtr(Int32& length)
w System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetQueryStringRawBytes()
w System.Web.HttpRequest.get_QueryStringBytes()
w System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInQueryStringCollection()
w System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureQueryString()
w System.Web.HttpRequest.get_QueryString()
w System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_QueryString()
w project.Infrastructure.Attributes.ErrorHandlingAttribute.BuildErrorEmail(Exception exc, HttpContextBase context) w c:\Users\Marcin Bigoraj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\project\Infrastructure\Attributes\ErrorHandlingAttribute.cs:wiersz 141
w project.Infrastructure.Attributes.ErrorHandlingAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<OnException>b__1() w c:\Users\Marcin Bigoraj\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\project\Infrastructure\Attributes\ErrorHandlingAttribute.cs:wiersz 182
w System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
w System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: I just tested this in a controller, and it works like a charm, without any exceptions. Could you post more related code? Maybe the whole attribute if possible?

Answer (score 7):

Check this code

```
if (Request.QueryString.Keys.Count > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: This is GREAT! checking to see if it's null wasn't working for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if there are any values in the QueryString by checking its count:

```
Request.QueryString.Count > 0;
```

It is sufficient.

Comment: -1 if the QueryString is null you will get an exception

Comment: Even with this I have the same exception.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ sry I would but I cant: "your last answer was ... ago. Your vote is locked..."